# Multi-client server use: which method better

Tags: java, multithreading, server, client, chat

Creating multi-client server use extends `Thread` or implements `Runnable` in Java.

Using

```
public class Receiver implements Runnable {
```

or

```
public class Receiver extends Thread {
```

Which one is better for my code?

Comment: People will enjoy reading your questions more if you stop shouting at them. Using all caps on the internet is shouting. Especially, why did you should "IN JAVA" when you've already used the java tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is always better to Implement Runnable, In case you are using Runnable u can execute  it with a thread or threadpool

Please read
["implements Runnable" vs "extends Thread" in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541487/implements-runnable-vs-extends-thread-in-java)

for more details

Answer (score 0):

Here are some links that can help you find your answer

> https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/implement-runnable-vs-extend-thread-in-java/
> ["implements Runnable" vs "extends Thread" in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541487/implements-runnable-vs-extends-thread-in-java)

In your specific case I think (guess) that your *Receiver* class **is not a Thread** (by means of OOP) but **should work in a Thread** or **Perform Multi-threaded** which means it should not extends Thread (there is no **is-a** relationship between *Receiver* and *Thread*)

Answer (score 0):

## Executors framework

I assume you meant “multi-threaded” where you wrote “multi client server”.

In modern Java we rarely manage threads manually. We now have the Executors framework to handle the details of juggling threads. So no need to extend `Thread`.

Tasks to be run on a background thread should be written as either a `Runnable` or a `Callable`, and then submitted to an executor service. See the `Executors` class to produce an executor service.

You get back a `Future` object that can be checked for the task being done, cancelled, or still pending.

This has been addressed many times already on Stack Overflow. Search to learn more.